# MVC How do I create a new object with default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view that has add/edit, edit is working fine but for add I would like to set default values for type. Is there a way to do this in the view the cshtml file?

add view

```
@Html.Partial("RegimenReferences", new (ReferencesModel {Type = "defaultType}") )
```

edit view

```
@Html.Partial("RegimenReferences", (ReferencesModel)Model)
```

Model

```
    public class ReferencesModel
    {
        public ReferencesModel()
        {

        }
        public ReferencesModel(Reference reference)
        {
            this.Id = reference.Id;
            this.Link = reference.Link;
            this.Text = reference.Text;
            this.Type = reference.Type;
            this.Regimens = reference.Regimens;
            this.GuidelineId = reference.GuidelineId;
            this.SortOrder = reference.SortOrder;
        }


        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Regimens { get; set; }
        public Guid? GuidelineId { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting to set those types specifically in cshtml?

Could you create a new constructor for your model that takes in any fields you want to set with a default?

```
public class ReferencesModel
    {
        public ReferencesModel(string type = null)
        {
            Type = type;
        }

        public ReferencesModel(Reference reference)
        {
            this.Id = reference.Id;
            this.Link = reference.Link;
            this.Text = reference.Text;
            this.Type = reference.Type;
            this.Regimens = reference.Regimens;
            this.GuidelineId = reference.GuidelineId;
            this.SortOrder = reference.SortOrder;
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Regimens { get; set; }
        public Guid? GuidelineId { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    }
```

or just set a default value in the constructor/in variable declaration

```
public ReferencesModel()
    {
        Type = "default type";
    }

public string Type = "default type";
```

Comment: I wanted to set the values in the cshtml

Comment: At the point of calling a partial? does @Html.Partial("RegimenReferences", new ReferencesModel {Type = "defaultType"} ) not work?

or using a constructor to do @Html.Partial("RegimenReferences", new ReferencesModel("default type"))

Comment: **Note:** `public string Type = "default type";` defines a public _field_. To set a public _property_ with a default value you need to use `public string Type { get; set; } = "default type";`. Otherwise you will be introducing a breaking change to your public interface later should you choose to make this a full property.

Comment: Also, you should define the default in your constructor _or_ as a default value on the property. There’s no need to do _both_.